# How do I do a partial match in Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, regex, parsing, url, elasticsearch

I have a link like http://drive.google.com and I want to match "google" out of the link.

I have:

```
query: {
    bool : {
        must: {
            match: { text: 'google'} 
        }
    }
}
```

But this only matches if the whole text is 'google' (case insensitive, so it also matches Google or GooGlE etc). How do I match for the 'google' inside of another string?

Comment: Perhaps `match: { text: '.*google.*'}` can help.

Comment: Awesome that worked! Can you put your answer as an 'Answer' so I can pick it to be the best one?

Comment: I have added the answer and supplied some relevant reference.

Comment: You need to put version numbers here so the correct solution gets posted for your version.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The point is that the ElasticSearch regex you are using [requires a *full string match*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators):

> **Lucene’s patterns are always anchored**. The pattern provided **must match the entire string**.

Thus, to match any character (but a newline), you can use `.*` pattern:

```
match: { text: '.*google.*'}
                ^^      ^^
```

In ES6+, use `regexp` insted of `match`:

```
"query": {
   "regexp": { "text": ".*google.*"} 
}
```

One more variation is for cases when your string can have newlines: `match: { text: '(.|\n)*google(.|\n)*'}`. This awful `(.|\n)*` is a must in ElasticSearch because this regex flavor does not allow any `[\s\S]` workarounds, nor any DOTALL/Singleline flags. [*"The Lucene regular expression engine is not Perl-compatible but supports a smaller range of operators."*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax)

**However**, if you do not plan to match any complicated patterns and need no word boundary checking, regex search for a mere substring is better performed with a mere **wildcard search**:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "text": {
                "value": "*google*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [**Wildcard search**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) for more details.

**NOTE**: The wildcard pattern also needs to match the whole input string, thus

- `google*` finds all strings *starting with* `google`
- `*google*` finds all strings *containing* `google`
- `*google` finds all strings *ending with* `google`

Also, bear in mind the only pair of special characters in wildcard patterns:

```
?, which matches any single character
*, which can match zero or more characters, including an empty one
```

Comment: @Battousai Feel free to post a question. Most probably there is a problem with *how* you are using the regex.

Comment: Set a good analyzer to split on dot for example by using standard analyzer or custom analyzer instead using wildcard query. It's consuming lot of resources and it's really not the elasticsearch logic...

Comment: @NicolasY It is the only way to do with a regex. And its resource consuming character is explained in the docs.

Comment: "google"  is a term so no need to do a regex to find it. Regex query is use to find a pattern not a term. It's a complete opposite of the Elasticseach logic.

Comment: @NicolasY "google" is an example. Ony could use `[0-9]+ gr[ea]y hats?` instead.

Comment: This is a differente case. In you last case you're right, this is the way to do.  But regarding the question asked by @user3835653 regex must not be the solution. I saw lot of projects with regex implementation.. because people don't know how to configure tokenizer and analyzer...

Comment: [Anchoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators) is what was making all my searches fail. Extremely useful info.

Comment: @drweird Added the ES6 version.

Comment: wildcard for the win.

Answer (score 39):

use wildcard query:

```
'{"query":{ "wildcard": { "text.keyword" : "*google*" }}}'
```

Comment: This query (wildcard) is the one that worked for me:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Answer (score 22):

For both partial and full text matching ,the following worked

```
"query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "*searchText*",
      "fields" : [
        "fieldName"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

I can't find a [breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) disabling regular expressions in `match`, but `match: { text: '.*google.*'}` does not work on any of my Elasticsearch 6.2 clusters. Perhaps it is configurable?

[Regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) works:

```
"query": {
   "regexp": { "text": ".*google.*"} 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For partial matching you can either use [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) or [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html).

Comment: The correct url for match phrase prefix: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic solution you can look into using a different analyzer or defining your own. I am assuming you are using the standard analyzer which would split http://drive.google.com into the tokens "http" and "drive.google.com". This is why the search for just google isn't working because it is trying to compare it to the full "drive.google.com".

If instead you indexed your documents using the simple analyzer it would split it up into "http", "drive", "google", and "com". This will allow you to match anyone of those terms on their own.

Answer (score 0):

using node.js client

**tag_name** is the field name, value is the incoming search value.

```
  const { body } = await elasticWrapper.client.search({
        index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
        body: {
          query: {
            wildcard: {
              tag_name: {
                value: `*${value}*`,
                boost: 1.0,
                rewrite: 'constant_score',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a wildcard search. According to the official documentation, it can be done as follows:

```js
query_string: {
  query: `*${keyword}*`,
  fields: ["fieldOne", "fieldTwo"],
},
```

> Wildcard searches can be run on individual terms, using ? to replace a single character, and * to replace zero or more characters: qu?ck bro*

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-wildcard

Be careful, though:

> Be aware that wildcard queries can use an enormous amount of memory and perform very badly — just think how many terms need to be queried to match the query string "a* b* c*".

> Allowing a wildcard at the beginning of a word (eg "*ing") is particularly heavy, because all terms in the index need to be examined, just in case they match. Leading wildcards can be disabled by setting allow_leading_wildcard to false.