# not able to find a word which is separated by (.)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-5

I am new to ELk .I am not able to find a word which is separated by (.) for example: javax.ejb.duplicatekeyexception
so when i only search duplicatekeyexception . kibana does not show any result , kindly please help me in resolving this issue .I am using logstash 2.4 , elasticsearch 5(current version),kibana 5(current version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a partial match in Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709100/how-do-i-do-a-partial-match-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: this is what i am exceuting in kibana dev tool:

PUT customindex1
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
"analyzer": {
"point_analyzer": {
"type": "pattern",
"pattern": "\.|\s"
}
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"dotanlayzer": {
"properties": {
"message": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "point_analyzer"
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: PUT _template/customtemplate
{
"order": 0,
"template": "logdemo1-*",
"settings": {
"analysis": {
"analyzer": {
"point_analyzer": {
"type": "pattern",
"pattern": "\.|\s"
}
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"dotanlayzer": {
"properties": {
"message": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "point_analyzer"
}
}
}
}
}

Reply

Comment: edit your question and add your query there

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your mapping? You could change your mapping so that field does not tokenize the values and preserves the whole value using the keyword field type. This requires you to reindex though if you want to keep your data. You could this with the reindex API.

See:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: path => "xyz/s.log"  
start_position => "beginning" 
sincedb_path => "xyz/loginput1.sincedb"
ignore_older => 0
codec => multiline {
pattern => "^\s"
what => "previous"
}
}
}
filter
{
date {
match => ["timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
target => "@timestamp"
add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
}
}

Comment: output {
stdout {  codec => rubydebug 
            }
if "xyz1" in [message] {
email {
to => 'technical@logstash.net'
from => 'monitor@logstash.net'
subject => 'Alert - %{title}'
body => "Tags: %{tags}\n\Content:\n%{message}"
domain => 'mail.logstash.net'
port => 25
}
}
}

Comment: elasticsearch {

  action => "index"
  hosts => "localhost" 
     
     index => "logdemo12" }

Comment: this is what i am exceuting in kibana dev tool:

PUT customindex1
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
"analyzer": {
"point_analyzer": {
"type": "pattern",
"pattern": "\.|\s"
}
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"dotanlayzer": {
"properties": {
"message": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "point_analyzer"
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: PUT _template/customtemplate
{
"order": 0,
"template": "logdemo1-*",
"settings": {
"analysis": {
"analyzer": {
"point_analyzer": {
"type": "pattern",
"pattern": "\.|\s"
}
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"dotanlayzer": {
"properties": {
"message": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "point_analyzer"
}
}
}
}
}

Reply